# Atom 'spec' files not being tested

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine, atom-editor

Following up from my previous question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384903/how-do-atoms-spec-files-work), I am trying to get 'spec' files registered by Atom, which I have succeeded in, however now, no matter how many `describe` and `it`'s I do, it doesn't do anything when I test it.

I use the command, `apm test`, and all I get is:

```
[655:0527/083825:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(305)]  locale_file_path.empty() for locale English
[655:0527/083825:ERROR:file_io.cc(30)] read: expected 40, observed 0
[659:0527/083825:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(305)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale English
[655:0527/083828:INFO:CONSOLE(52)] "Window load time: 2420ms", source: file:///Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/static/index.js (52)


Finished in 0.023 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped

Tests passed
```

Judging by the spec file (which **is definitely being registered**, as it complains when it doesn't exist), I should have 3 tests run.

My spec file is as follows... (Syntax Highlighter package)

```
describe "Jazz grammar", ->
  grammar = null

  beforeEach ->
    waitsForPromise ->
      atom.packages.activatePackage("language-jazz")

    runs ->
      grammar = atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName("source.jazz")

    it "parses the grammar", ->
        expect(grammar).toBeDefined()
        expect(grammar.scopeName).toBe "source.jazz"

    it "tokenises keywords", ->
        tokens = grammar.tokenizeLines('func')

        expect(tokens[0][0].value).toBe 'func'
        expect(tokens[0][0].scopes).toEqual ['source.jazz', 'storage.type.jazz']

    it "tokenizes comments inside function parameters", ->
        tokens = grammar.tokenizeLines('module test(arg1, ;; arg2)')

        expect(tokens[0][0].value).toBe 'module'
        expect(tokens[0][0].scopes).toEqual ['source.jazz', 'storage.type.jazz']
        expect(tokens[0][1].scopes).toEqual ['source.jazz', 'comment.line.jazz']
```

My file structure is as follows:

- language-jazz

  - grammars

    - `jazz.cson`
  - snippets

    - `language-jazz.cson`
  - spec

    - `jazz-spec.coffee`
  - `package.json`
  - Other GitHub and Travis CI stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the indentation and structure of your tests in your spec, bear in mind that in CoffeeScript whitespace is significant and the `run` blocks are used to encapsulate blocks of the code not to group `it` statements.

So the spec should be:

```
describe "Jazz grammar", ->
  grammar = null

  beforeEach ->
    waitsForPromise ->
      atom.packages.activatePackage("language-jazz")

  grammar = atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName("source.jazz")

  it "parses the grammar", ->
    expect(grammar).toBeDefined()
    expect(grammar.scopeName).toBe "source.jazz"

  it "tokenises keywords", ->
    tokens = grammar.tokenizeLines('func')

    expect(tokens[0][0].value).toBe 'func'
    expect(tokens[0][0].scopes).toEqual ['source.jazz', 'storage.type.jazz']

  it "tokenizes comments inside function parameters", ->
    tokens = grammar.tokenizeLines('module test(arg1, ;; arg2)')

    expect(tokens[0][0].value).toBe 'module'
    expect(tokens[0][0].scopes).toEqual ['source.jazz', 'storage.type.jazz']
    expect(tokens[0][1].scopes).toEqual ['source.jazz', 'comment.line.jazz']
```

I've tested this locally and it shows up as three failing tests, as I have implemented your grammar.

Comment: Sorry, I just made a template from `language-python`. I'm using four-space indentation, however you're using two-space ones. Either way, I'm cringing at how simple the answer was, thankyou very much again Richard; now I just need to diagnose the failures...

Comment: I added the `runs ->` back in, and it seems to have fixed the "grammer.tokenizeLines` not found errors. Check out: https://github.com/atom/language-python/blob/master/spec/python-spec.coffee for the `runs` thing.